# How to cover IF statement in Junit testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I am new to Juint Testing. I am having difficulty in covering all the lines of  the below Method:

```
private GetMWSAuthTokenByOwnerAndSignatoryResult getMWSAuthToken(SellerUniversalId ownerId, SellerUniversalId signatoryId,boolean isContractAvailable) {
    try {
        String mwsAuthToken = this.mwsClientAdapter.getMWSAuthToken(
                signatoryId.getMarketplaceMerchant().getMerchantId(),
                ownerId.getMarketplaceMerchant().getMerchantId());
        return buildGetMWSAuthTokenByOwnerAndSignatoryResult(mwsAuthToken);
    } catch (MWSAuthTokenDoesNotExistException e) {
        if (isContractAvailable == false) {
            return GetMWSAuthTokenByOwnerAndSignatoryResult.builder().build();
        } else {
            throw new MWSAuthTokenNotFoundException(e);
        }
    }
```

***The Junit for the else part was already there but i am not able to cover the If part when isContractAvailable == false.***

*Junit Code for the else part is* -

```
@Test(expected = MWSAuthTokenNotFoundException.class)
public void testMwsAuthThrowsTokenNotFoundException() throws StorageException, MWSException, MWSAuthTokenDoesNotExistException {
    mockContract0.withOwnerId(mockOwnerId);
    mockContracts = Arrays.asList(mockContract0.get());
    mockContractStorage.withGetContractsBySignatoryId(mockSellerId, mockState, mockContracts);
    when( mockMwsClientAdapter.getMWSAuthToken(mockSellerMerchantId, mockOwnerMerchantId) )
            .thenThrow(new MWSAuthTokenDoesNotExistException("message"));

    GetMWSAuthTokenByOwnerAndSignatoryActivity activity = new GetMWSAuthTokenByOwnerAndSignatoryActivity(
            mockContext.get(), mockMwsClientAdapter, mockMetricsHelper);
    activity.enact(getActivityInput( mockOwnerId, mockSellerId ));
}
```

**WHat should be the Juint test case for covering  the If Part?** I am using JUnit-4

Comment: why are you checking ```isContractAvailable == false```,
why wouldn't you use ```!isContractAvailable``` or vice versa

Comment: by writing test scenario's that test both outcomes

Comment: also it depends on your logic, this is a private method, so you need to find out where this is being called from and then test that method with different situation. If worst comes to worst, you can use ReflectionTestUtils library or other ReflectionLibrary to invoke private method but this isn't ideal

Answer (score 0):

Can you find the part where the activity calls that method you're trying to test? And how does it determine the `isContractAvailable` parameter?
Is it generated code or custom code?

It's probably something related to the ContractStorage, so you should find a way to set up the `mockContractStorage` to assure that `isContractAvailable` becomes false.

Maybe something like:

```
mockContractStorage.withGetContractsBySignatoryId(mockSellerId, mockState, 
                                                Collections.emptyList());
```

Comment: isContractAvailable is a value determined on the caller method of this method and passed as arguement. The flag value has significance only when it is false and MWSAuthTokenDoesNotExistException is getting thrown.

Comment: the question is: _how_ is isContractAvailable determined, and can you change the mocks so it is false?